# How to change default attack direction for player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I coded my player in my platform game so that he would attack with a sword when you press space. It attacks right when I run right. It attacks left when I run left. But when I stand still by default it attacks left. How do I make it attack right instead?

Below is all the code in my player controller script, and also an image of my blend tree.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int moveSpeed;

    private Animator anim;

    public int playerJumpPower = 1250;
    private float moveX;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public float fJumpWaitTime = 0.2f;
    private float fJumpWait;
    private object col;
    private bool attacking;
    public float attackTime;
    private float attackTimeCounter;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!attacking)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                Jump();
            }
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
            {
                transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
            }
            void Jump()
            {
                //Jumping Code
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * playerJumpPower);
                isGrounded = false;
            }
            void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player has collided with " + col.collider.name);
                if (col.gameObject.tag == "ground")
                {
                    isGrounded = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            attackTimeCounter = attackTime;
            attacking = true;   
            anim.SetBool("Attack", true);    
        }
if(attackTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            attackTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

if(attackTimeCounter <= 0)
        {
            attacking = false;
            anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you play either attack right or attack left? The code you added only plays the attack animation and doesn't distinguish between them.

Comment: I want it to be attack right when I stand still and attack not attack left

Comment: Yeah the problem is you only attack left it only seems to attack right because you flipped your character (at least that's what I'm guessing hard to tell without more code and without seeing the blend tree).

Comment: I sent the image of blend tree

Comment: Added an answer. Your code seems fine and shouldn't make a problem besides that having void `OnCollisionEnter2D(){}` inside of your Update shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having another look at your Blend Tree, I would check if your Threst is the problem.

**What you have right now:**

PlayerAttackLeft 0 -1

PlayerAttackRight 1 1

**What you should probably have:**

PlayerAttackLeft -0.01 -1

PlayerAttackRight 0 1

[image: Image of what I mean]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218081/discussion-on-answer-by-mathewhd-i-am-making-a-platform-game-in-unity-i-made-co).